# Control and up/down keys in terminal for use by emacs

Tags: terminal, emacs, keyboard

Is it possible to use `C-up` and `C-down` when running emacs in the terminal window (when starting emacs from the command line with the `-nw` flag)? What should my terminal send when I press `C-up` and `C-down` for these keys to work in emacs?

I'm on Mac OSX, using iterm2 to ssh into a remote linux server, where I start the emacs session from bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terminals know characters, not keys, so keys with no corresponding character need to be translated into escape sequences and back.

You can pick any control sequences that doesn't cause any conflict and that iterm2 and Emacs agree on. Unfortunately, these control sequences aren't standardized. `\e[1;5A` and `\e[1;5B` are popular choices (where `\e` is an escape character).

Emacs has a fairly complex system to translate escape sequences into keys. See [translation keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) in the manual. Use `input-decode-map` unless you have an old version of Emacs that doesn't have it.

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5A" [C-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;5B" [C-down])
```

In iterm2, set the corresponding key sequences in the “Keys” tab in your profile. See [How can I get control+left arrow to go back one word in iTerm2?](https://superuser.com/questions/357355/how-can-i-get-controlleft-arrow-to-go-back-one-word-in-iterm2) for an illustrated guide.

See also [Emacs + paredit under terminal (Terminal.app, iTerm, iTerm2)](http://offbytwo.com/2012/01/15/emacs-plus-paredit-under-terminal.html).

Comment: Thanks Gilles. Do you know if there is a way to look up those control sequences for a given sequence of keyboard strokes? For example, I would like to look up `Control + Shift + j` to pass it to `kbd` later in my `.emacs` file

Comment: @roseck [I've answered your related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47508/string-syntax-for-the-kbd-macro-in-emacs/47509#47509). `C-S-j` is probably send by the terminal in exactly the same way as `C-j`, though; how to change that is heavily dependent on your terminal emulator.