# String syntax for the kbd macro in Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associating a function in Emacs after looking up the code with M-x describe-key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47360/associating-a-function-in-emacs-after-looking-up-the-code-with-m-x-describe-key)

I have typed the following macros on my `.emacs` file

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<left>") 'windmove-left)          ; move to left windnow
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<right>") 'windmove-right)        ; move to right window
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>") 'windmove-up)              ; move to upper window
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<down>") 'windmove-down)          ; move to lower window
```

However, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> or any of the other keyboard combinations, I get errors like the following in the minibuffer `M-o 3 c is undefined`.

Why doesn't it work? I thought I was following the syntax described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html) (`kbd` macro).

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. This question is actually inspired by your answer to the other question. The `kbd` documentation I point to (and the same link you included in your answer) shows specifically an example with `(kbd "C-M-<down>") `. If so, why do I have to drop the angle brackets?

Comment: @Gilles: The documentation specifically says: "you must surround function key names with `<...>`",  and gives `<down>` as an example for the input to `kbd` (bottom of the page).

Comment: Ah, oops, yeah, sorry.

Comment: Your problem is the same as [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47312/control-and-up-down-keys-in-terminal-for-use-by-emacs), so you need to declare that `"\eO3c"` is `M-left` in `input-decode-map` and so on. Is that close enough for a duplicate, or do you need a more precise answer?

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. I guess that I am still surprised to see that the official Emacs documentation is wrong on something as fundamental as keyboard bindings, but you probably know better, so I leave it up to you to close this thread or leave it open.

Comment: The documentation isn't wrong, this bit is mentioned in a [different section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#Translation-Keymaps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminals know characters, not keys, so keys with no corresponding character need to be translated into escape sequences and back. When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, it is translated into the sequence of characters `\eO3d` where `\e` is an escape character. Unfortunately, some of these character sequences are not standardized, so you need to declare what your terminal sends to Emacs.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> then the key combination (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>) to enter the key sequence in a buffer. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> command tells Emacs to interpret the leading escape character literally. You'll see something like `^[O3d` where that `^[` is not the two characters `^[` but an escape character, better written in an Emacs Lisp string as `\e`.

Add each key combination's escape sequence to [`input-decode-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#Translation-Keymaps). For example (this code goes into your `.emacs`):

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\eO3a" [M-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\eO3b" [M-down])
(define-key input-decode-map "\eO3c" [M-right])
(define-key input-decode-map "\eO3d" [M-left])
```

`(kbd "M-<up>")` or `(kbd "<M-up>")` are alternative ways of writing `[M-up]`.

Once you've declared these translations, Emacs will know that when the terminal sends e.g. `^[O3d` it stands for the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, and your bindings will work.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow typing `Ctrl+Q` is not working for me, i.e. I don't get the escape sequence. Is there another way of invoking the function called by `Ctrl+Q` ?

Comment: @roseck `M-x quoted-insert`. If `C-q` and `C-s` aren't working, see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Modes.html

Comment: @Gilles, sorry for bringing back an old question, in my case, after `C-q` and my desired key combo (`Alt+CMD+left`, where `Alt` is my `Meta`), all I get is `^[C` as the escape sequence. According to your answer above, `^[` is the escape character for the meta key `Alt`, but what about the characters for `CMD` and `left` keys? I am using Emacs inside iTerm2 in OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: @MLister There's no standard for Cmd. It's possible that `Alt+Cmd+Left` sends an Esc character to represent Alt, followed by an escape sequence starting with Esc. In this case, Emacs receives two Esc characters and so the C-q trick doesn't work. Almost always in this case, the escape sequence is the same that Cmd+Left sends, so see what that sends and bind that sequence with an extra `\e` at the beginning.

Comment: @Gilles, you are right about the issue with `CMD` key, as my searches also lead me the same conclusion. However, what still puzzles me is that I then try `Ctrl+Alt+left` with the `C-q` trick, where `Alt` is still my `Meta`, nothing is output to the buffer (no escape sequence displayed). I wonder if this is related to some sort of key mapping setting(s) in iTerm2 and possibly OS X more generally. Is there any way to find out?

Comment: @MLister It's possible that this is bound to some OSX user interface function, so it's eaten up by the OS or by iTerm2 itself. I wouldn't know as I'm not an OSX user, I suggest asking on [apple.se] where you'll find the most expertise on OSX user interface.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for all your pointers, using [this link](http://offbytwo.com/2012/01/15/emacs-plus-paredit-under-terminal.html) in one of your other answers, I am able to fix the issue by adding key mappings to iTerm2 profile.